# Is there a word that refers to both caller and callee in telecommunication?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word that can refer to both caller and callee as in calling party and called party in **telecommunication**?

Comment: Perhaps *interlocutor*, although it is not limited to telephony.

Comment: Why not just _party_?

Comment: @anemone Naming it just _party_ seems too ambiguous. Do you think _call party_ is a word?

Comment: Please include an example sentence, so that we can better understand how you want to use this word.

Comment: @DanielShin Whether it's ambiguous or not depends on context. If you want the word "call" or "phone" or similar root to be explicitly included, you might have difficulty to find a single word. However, _party_ is native to telecom. and is better than "user" and like, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ***(call) participant***?

Comment: _call participant_ is a good word. But is a little mouthful (as in I need to type it out in my program repeatedly). Could we replace _participant_ with something more brief?

Comment: Well, I think that, given the context, *participant* will be understood just fine. If that is too long, then you could go with *party*, as mentioned elsewhere. I don't think *participant* is too long though, and it's completely unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

In telecommunication, the word *party* [is established](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone#Details_of_operation) in the sense "caller or callee".

> A calling party wishing to speak to another party will pick up the telephone's handset, [...]

[the linked Wikipedia entry]

Answer (score 0):

Telecommunication being the context, I prefer the term ***subscribers***. Or simply ***users*** (of the Telecom service)

Answer (score 0):

In a normal telephone conversation, the parties can be figuratively depicted as sender and receiver.
In a WebEx, the parties in the communication process are attendee (participant) and speaker (facilitator).

In general, both could be referred to as "communicators."

Since you have to use it repeatedly, you may consider using caller and the "B-number."
Hope this helps!